# C++ maps, vectors, pairs with references

Tags: c++, reference, containers

I am trying to share references between a map and another vector as in the following code:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T& x) {

  std::map<T, vector<int> > mp;
  mp[x] = vector<int>(2, 4);

  vector< pair<T&, int> > v1;

  for (auto& kv : mp) {
    v1.push_back( make_pair(kv.first, 0) );
  }

}
```

and call this function from another

```
int x = 2;
f(x);
```

But this does not compile.

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::pair<int&, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int&, int> > >::push_back(std::pair<int, int>)’
     v1.push_back( make_pair(kv.first, 0) );
```

Does anybody see why?

**EDIT**
I was able to make things work with

```
std::reference_wrapper
```

Here is my current solution.

```
template <typename T>
void f(T& x) {

  std::map<std::reference_wrapper<T>, vector<int> > mp;
  mp[x] = vector<int>(2, 4);

  vector< pair<T&, int> > v1;

  for (auto& kv : mp) {
    v1.push_back( make_pair( std::ref(kv.first) , 0) );
  }

  v1[0].first = 34;
}
```

And

```
int x = 2;
f(x);
cout << x << endl;
```

prints 34. Do people see any cons with this vs the pointer based approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can store `std::pair<T&,int>` in an `std::vector`, but you have to insert values correctly.
`make_pair(x, 0)` creates a `std::pair<T,int>` with no reference.

You can for example use an initializer lists instead:

```
 v.push_back({x,0});
```

Another method would be using `std::ref`:

```
v.push_back(std::make_pair(std::ref(x),0));
```

**Example:**

```
std::vector<std::pair<int&,int>> v;
int a = 1;
v.push_back({a,a});
v.push_back(std::make_pair(std::ref(a),a));
a = 2;
std::cout << v[0].first << " " << v[0].second << std::endl; // will write "2 1"
```

---

However for your purpose it will not work. You should not get references to keys of a `std::map`. A `std::map` is a sorted container, you can not just change a key from the outside. This would mess up the inner workings of the `std::map`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a container of references.

A reference must be initialized at the point of declaration, and declaring a container of references implies filling that container later on.

You could use pointers instead. Non (memory) owning pointers are considered valid c++ style.

Second option would be to [look into](https://ideone.com/zIUkDZ)

```
std::reference_wrapper
```

Comment: It is very well possible to have a container which stores `pair<T&, int>`!

Comment: @Danvil Really?  A reference is neither copiable nor movable; the same applies to a pair which contains a reference.  All of the standard containers require that the contained objects be either copiable or movable.

Answer (score 1):

Because of type mismatch:

```
vector< pair<T&, int> > v1;   // value_type is pair<int&, int>
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and

```
v1.push_back( make_pair(kv.first, 0) );
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      pair<int, int>
```

A lvalue-reference to int cannot be initialized with an rvalue.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to reference the same object in your map and your vector of pairs, then you'd be better off looking at a pointer based solution. If your original type is stack based then your secondary collection could use a raw pointer - since it does not have ownership of the key object and so should not take any role in retaining or destructing it - to deference it. Although you'll have to be careful about managing the two collections in sync to avoid any dangling pointers.

That said, depending on why you want to do it, if it's a simple `int`  it may not be worth the complexity.

Comment: `shared_ptr` is definitely not a good solution in general; presumably, if he wants references, the objects are managed elsewhere---most likely with static or auto lifetime.  Raw pointers are the best solution here.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes, if that's the case, you're right - raw pointers would be a better solution. I'll update answer to clarify.